# Disable ruffle on web.archive.org

Tags: javascript, flash, ruffle

Please help me with a flash game, I want run it for my kid. It is not on the web anymore but it exists in the archive. The game is in 3D and ruffle does not run it correctly. I wanted to use some other flash emulators, but I can't disable ruffle on web.archive.org. Maybe it is possible to disable it from console somehow or use a greasemonkey script? I tried to add ruffle-related-js-files to ignore list in dev. tools but it doesn't seem to work, ruffle just keeps showing up...

The game: https://web.archive.org/web/20150219085039/http://www.karusel-tv.ru/games/karusel/constructor

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ruffle isn't loaded when flash support exists in the browser...